# DotNet 6 gateway-service without de-/serialization

Tags: .net, rest, serialization

I want to build a gateway-service to seperate my backend-rest-services from the UI.
Every service-call the UI performs is sent to this gateway and the request is passed to a backend-service (also the response is returned).

The transfered data-objects can be very big. Because of this I want to avoid double de-/serialization.

Example:
[image]

How can this be achieved while still using the correct data-class from a nuget-package in those services?
Can serializers be told to serialize only if the object is accessed? Are there packages or tools to wrap data-classes?